# Python Sockets Left in UNCONN State

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I am facing an issue where my sockets in ubuntu are left in UNCONN State:

```
ss -s
```

[image]

And below are the state for better visibility

```
ss -au
```

[image]

I am using a python code that is trying to use sockets to receive audio streams and the basic function to create a socket looks like the below :

```
    def find_incoming_port_multiplier(self, ip, alias,port=0, min_port=1000, max_port=11000):
    if min_port > 0:
        port = min_port + alias

    while port <= max_port:
        if port in Controller.port_info:
            logger.info('port already present in port_info' + str(port))
            port += 1000
            continue

        try:
            listeningAddress = (ip, port)
            logger.info("Looking for PORT " + str(listeningAddress))
            datagramSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

            #End the socket in 30 seconds ... just a precaution
            datagramSocket.settimeout(30)

            datagramSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            logger.info("Trying Binding... " + str(listeningAddress))
            datagramSocket.bind(listeningAddress)


            logger.info("Final Port Allocated " + str(listeningAddress))
            return datagramSocket, datagramSocket.getsockname()[1]
        except OSError:
            logger.info('PORT ' + str(port) + ' already in use')
            port += 1000
    raise IOError('no free ports')
```

The socket object from the above function is used by a new thread and ends once the processing is done.

I am still not determined whether it's something to do with linux **OR** how the socket is created.

Killing the code forcefully all the sockets are released. Interestingly the same issue is not present if the OS is windows.

**SO JUST TO EXPLAIN FURTHER AS REQUESTED:**

1. The Function above shared an unconnected socket
2. The unconnected socket is set as a variable of a class, and thread is started to process it
3. The socket is finally closed at the end

   ```
   try:
       while (True):
           self.pi.incoming_sock.settimeout(5)
           try:
               message, sourceAddress = self.pi.incoming_sock.recvfrom(self.incoming_packet_size)
           except:
               logger.info('Stream closed.. exiting loop')
               break
           self.stream.write(message)
   except:
       logger.exception(traceback.print_exc())
   finally:
       if self.pi is not None and self.pi.incoming_sock is not None:
           self.pi.incoming_sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
           self.pi.incoming_sock.close()
   ```

I was earlier assuming that the threads are not dying but using the Htop command on Linux I can see that at any point the threads are no more than 200 but sockets reach around 52K and then the process hangs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. You are creating unconnected UDP sockets to receive data from arbitrary sources (connected would only receive data from the specific connected source) - so of course the socket shows up as unconnected.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich I have added some more data points in the case that helps...

Comment: The code is to incomplete to be usable to fully understand and reproduce what happens. I recommend that you log not only in the places where the socket get created but also where it should be closed. Then you can check if the closing is actually done. Also, it makes no sense to shutdown the socket before closing it, i.e. `close` is all you need.

Comment: When I close a UDP socket created as you have, it no longer shows in `ss -au`.